# Equivalent of `shift` from pandas

Tags: c#, dataframe, ml.net, dotnet-interactive

## Initial DataFrame in Pandas

Let's suppose we have the following in Python with pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Col1": [10, 20, 15, 30, 45],
    "Col2": [13, 23, 18, 33, 48],
    "Col3": [17, 27, 22, 37, 52] },
    index=pd.date_range("2020-01-01", "2020-01-05"))

df
```

Here's what we get in Jupyter:

[image]

## Shifting columns

Now let's `shift` `Col1` by 2 and store it in `Col4`.

We'll also store `df['Col1'] / df['Col1'].shift(2)` in `Col5`:

```py
df_2 = df.copy(deep=True)

df_2['Col4'] = df['Col1'].shift(2)

df_2['Col5'] = df['Col1'] / df['Col1'].shift(2)

df_2
```

The result:

[image]

## C# version

Now let's setup a similar `DataFrame` in C#:

```cs
#r "nuget:Microsoft.Data.Analysis"

using Microsoft.Data.Analysis;
var df = new DataFrame(
    new PrimitiveDataFrameColumn<DateTime>("DateTime",
        Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select(i => new DateTime(2020, 1, 1).Add(new TimeSpan(i, 0, 0, 0)))),    
    new PrimitiveDataFrameColumn<int>("Col1", new []{ 10, 20, 15, 30, 45 }),
    new PrimitiveDataFrameColumn<int>("Col2", new []{ 13, 23, 18, 33, 48 }),
    new PrimitiveDataFrameColumn<int>("Col3", new []{ 17, 27, 22, 37, 52 })
);

df
```

The result in .NET Interactive:

[image]

## Question

What's a good way to perform the equivalent column shifts as demonstrated in the Pandas version?

## Notes

The above example is from the documentation for `pandas.DataFrame.shift`:

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html

## Update

It does indeed look like there isn't currently a built-in `shift` in `Microsoft.Data.Analysis`. I've posted an issue for this here:

https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/6008

Answer (score 0):

## Helper functions

Perform a column shift.

```cs
PrimitiveDataFrameColumn<double> ShiftIntColumn(PrimitiveDataFrameColumn<int> col, int n, string name)
{
    return 
        new PrimitiveDataFrameColumn<double>(
            name,
            Enumerable.Repeat((double?) null, n)
                .Concat(col.Select(item => (double?) item))
                .Take(col.Count()));
}
```

Carry out division, taking care of `null` values in divisor.

```cs
PrimitiveDataFrameColumn<double> DivAlt3(PrimitiveDataFrameColumn<int> a, PrimitiveDataFrameColumn<double> b, string name)
{
    return 
        new PrimitiveDataFrameColumn<double>(name, a.Zip(b, (x, y) => y == null ? null : x / y));
}
```

Then the following:

```cs
var df = new DataFrame(
    new PrimitiveDataFrameColumn<DateTime>("DateTime",
        Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select(i => 
            new DateTime(2020, 1, 1).Add(new TimeSpan(i, 0, 0, 0)))),    
    new PrimitiveDataFrameColumn<int>("Col1", new []{ 10, 20, 15, 30, 45 }),
    new PrimitiveDataFrameColumn<int>("Col2", new []{ 13, 23, 18, 33, 48 }),
    new PrimitiveDataFrameColumn<int>("Col3", new []{ 17, 27, 22, 37, 52 })
);

df.Columns.Add(ShiftIntColumn((PrimitiveDataFrameColumn<int>)df["Col1"], 2, "Col4"));

df.Columns.Add(DivAlt3((PrimitiveDataFrameColumn<int>) df["Col1"], (PrimitiveDataFrameColumn<double>) df["Col4"], "Col5"));
```

results in:

[image]

## Complete notebook

See the following notebook for a full demonstration of the above:

https://github.com/dharmatech/dataframe-shift-example-cs/blob/003/dataframe-shift-example-cs.ipynb

## Notes

- It would be great if `Microsoft.Data.Analysis` came with column `shift` functionality.
- It would also be great if column division handled nulls natively.

Would love to see other perhaps more idiomatic approaches to this.